# Does Hibernate Support Postgres 9.2 Json Data Type?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

It looks like Hibernate does not support Postgres Json datatype.

I am getting the following error:

`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111`

**Configuration:**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="PGDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>         
    </bean>
```

**Java Code:**

```
query = "select row_to_json(row) from ( " + query + ") row";

EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

List resultList = em.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
System.out.println("resultList " + resultList +  " resultList " + resultList.getClass());
```

Let me know if there are any workarounds.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Postgre, why shall you convert the row to JSON, when you need to feed it to ORM? The ORM is more happy with ROW itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapping postgreSQL JSON column to Hibernate value type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974474/mapping-postgresql-json-column-to-hibernate-value-type)

Answer (score 1):

You can define one more property in your `FactoryBean` called `Type Definitions`. Where you can provide a explicit class to map the data when it encounters json data type.

```xml
<property name="typeDefinitions">
    <list>
        <bean id="oracleXmlType" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.TypeDefinitionBean">
            <property name="typeName" value="jsonDataType" />
            <property name="typeClass" value="org.test.postgres.JsonDataType" />
        </bean> 
</property>
```

You need to create a mapping class `JSonDataType` to map the data from `jsonDatatype` to appropriate data type in Java or else you can check whether there is an existing mapper class available.