# Insert json value to postgresql table using Hibernate

Tags: java, json, hibernate, postgresql, usertype

I have a table with a column of type json in my postgreSQL DB (9.2). I'm using Hibernate and implemented the code example from [Mapping postgreSQL JSON column to Hibernate value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974474/mapping-postgresql-json-column-to-hibernate-value-type) suggested by [Tim Fulmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752693/tim-fulmer), But I keep getting the following exception :

```
ERROR: column "jsonobject" is of type json but expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I don't want to cast the expression because it is not recommended.
I getting this error when I'm using a table that was pre-generated and the column is of type json. When I'm changing Hibernate configuration to build the table for me, I don't get the exception and the value are inserted to the newly created table but the type of this column is '*character varying(255)*' instead of JSON.

I'm bet that I missed something in my implementation but can't understand what.
Where should I look ? 
I even tried to set breakpoints in my code but I don't reach them.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to use a custom Hibernate type, [create a cast in PostgreSQL to allow implicit conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15983429/398670), or cast at the SQL level.

Comment: Show your mappings. At a guess, you've added the type support code, but have not actually used it in your Hibernate mappings.

Comment: The column mapping : **<property name="someobjects" type="java.lang.String"> <column name="jsonobject" />** I tried to change the mapping but got exceptions that the type that I used is not known.

Comment: I think you'll need to specify `typeClass=` or similar. I don't work with Hibernate XML mappings, but you should be able to translate the annotations in the example given on the other answer.

Comment: I've added **@TypeDefs( {@TypeDef( name= "StringJsonObject", typeClass = StringJsonUserType.class)})** at the top of my class (as mentioned in the other answer), but it does not help. I don't think that the usertype class is even being called. You suggest that I should put the typeClass in my xml mapping file ?

Comment: As I said, I don't use Hibernate XML mappings. I suspect that maybe if you use XML mappings it doesn't see the annotation? The other possibility is that you did not specify the custom dialect.

Comment: I will try to use in Class mapping. Where should I specify the custom dialect ?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, the following definition was really missing from my project.
In the xml mapping file for the table I had to use *type="com.example.StringJsonUserType"* for that specific field instead of *type="java.lang.String"*
so the mapping for this column is :

```
<property name="someobjects" type="com.example.StringJsonUserType">
    <column name="jsonobject" />
</property>
```

Sagi.