# Is there a elegant and common way for converting PostgreSQL hstore to JPA 2.1 DataType?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I have used JPA 2.1 `Converter` to convert PostgreSQL `hstore` to `Map<String, String>`.
But I didn't find a universal way for different JPA providers such as EclipseLink and Hibernate. So I need to write different Converters for each JPA provider.

The following is the example which uses different Converters for EclipseLink and Hibernate.
https://github.com/phstudy/jpa-converter-sample

Is there an universal way for different JPA providers?

Comment: Really haven't heard of anything like this. maybe because hstore is not standard SQL datatype. It would be great if you could use something like @elementcollection on it, but even this solution would not allow you to query properly IMO

Comment: EclipseLink will take the object as is from the driver - getObject() is returning a map not a string.  So I don't think its an EclipseLink bug.  If you remove generics, will the EclipseLink converter not work in Hibernate?

Comment: Hi @Chris, Hibernate will throw `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unsupported Types value: 494,394,026`.  [The detailed exception](https://gist.github.com/phstudy/9466577)

Comment: @study -     
 
Could you manage to persist data in Postgres using this method? I get a is of type hstore but expression is of type character varying if treating as a String, or Unsupported Types value: <random numbers> if attempting as an Object.

Comment: Hi @Pool, which JPA provider do you use? Hibernate or EclipseLink?

Comment: I'm using Hibernate. After reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974474/mapping-postgresql-json-column-to-hibernate-value-type I concluded it is not possible without using Hibernate specific classes or (probably what I will use) modifying Postgres to allow automatic conversion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PostgreSQL JDBC driver provides a [`org.postgresql.util.HStoreConverter`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/util/HStoreConverter.html) utility class with to/from `String` and `byte[]` conversion. You can use it to implement your own JPA 2.1 [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Converter.html):

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.util.Map;
import org.postgresql.util.HStoreConverter;

@Converter
public class MyHStoreConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, String>, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, String> attribute) {
        return HStoreConverter.toString(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return HStoreConverter.fromString(dbData);
    }
}
```

Then, use it with the JPA [`Convert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html) annotation in your entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Convert(converter = MyHStoreConverter.class)
    private Map<String, String> hstoreAttribute;
}
```

This is an implementation using only JPA standards, so should be JPA-provider agnostic. However, using the `Converter` to map to a generic `Map<>` has earlier been blocked by the Hibernate bug [HHH-8804](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8804), but that has been fixed in Hibernate 5.0.0 and 4.3.11.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary any more. The current Postgres JDBC driver returns a `Map` instance when calling `ResultSet.getObject()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - would you care to post it as an answer together with an example? Having the setup as above, I removed the `@Convert` annotation and the application failed to start with an error `Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: MyEntity, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(hstoreAttribute)]` (Hibernate 4.3.11). So it does not seem to work just out of the box.

Comment: No idea. I don't use obfuscation layers like Hibernate. I just thought that Hibernate might be smart enough to properly deal with a `Map` instance.

Comment: @AdamMichalik thanks, I have updated my sample project. And it works with eclipselink and hibernate. https://github.com/phstudy/jpa-converter-sample

Comment: @AdamMichalik i tried with hibernate 5.2.10 and postgresql 9.6 and i get error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "fields" is of type hstore but expression is of type character varying
  Indice : You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: @roberttrudel I have no clue why that would be. Try posting it as a separate question with more details about your code.

Comment: @AdamMichalik already done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697665/not-able-to-save-hstore-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but my understanding is that the new JPA 2.1 `@Converter` has been designed to bring a universal way to create a custom types.

It looks like you have the right solution but you're having troubles with the EclipseLink and Hibernate implementations.

You probably can find your way out by handling all different cases in a single `convertToEntityAttribute(Object object)` method.

Comment: I have ever tried `convertToEntityAttribute(Object object)`, it will cause Hibernate to throw a exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried (parts of) your code, but get an exception when the table is generated: 
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Error: Type »hstore« does not exist (Postgresql 9.1). This means I have only an idea.  Try to define both methods:

```
@Override
convertToEntityAttribute(Object object)
```

and

```
//without @Override
convertToEntityAttribute(String string)
```

and then do the same for the other method. Eventually change which one is overriden.

PS: you could use the @ElementCollection annotation to directly map the `Map`, this way avoiding the Converters (if you are not working with a legacy DB that already has the data)

Comment: For PostgreSQL 9.1, you need to install the hstore extension manually. Use `CREATE EXTENSION hstore;`

Comment: I have also tried this, but the method `convertToEntityAttribute(String string)` will not be invoked.

Comment: Does it need to be invoked?  If Hibernate uses the Object one, it would just be used to get around the Hibernate exception you mentioned in an earlier comment.

Comment: This method maybe not require to be invoked, but I have declared both of them and also got the same Exception `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unsupported Types value: 494,394,026`.