# How to store Gson object as a Json type in postgres

Tags: java, json, postgresql, gson

I have datatype called "json" in postgres db. I wanted to insert data gson object from java code.

How can i insert gson object data into json column of table in postgres database?

Can any one help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

In Postgres SQL the **json** type is similar to **text** type and in java the corresponding mapping will be String type.The important thing is that json String must be valid json because there is a validation at database end.

[Refer this link for clarification](https://functionwhatwhat.com/json-in-postgresql/)

Comment: Unfortunately, PostgreSQL is painfully strict about typecasts, and will complain about a json vs text type mismatch. You'll need to `CREATE CAST` to make it work properly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974474/mapping-postgresql-json-column-to-hibernate-value-type/15983429#15983429