# How to map a Java Map to a PostgreSQL native json type

Tags: java, json, hibernate, postgresql

How can one map a Java Map to a PostgreSQL json data type ?

**Note that I want to map PostgreSQL-JSON-Data to a Java Map, and not to a String. Therefore I do not agree that my question is a duplicate of [Mapping postgreSQL JSON column to Hibernate value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974474/).**

Entity example:

```
@Entity
public class Test implements Serializable {

    ...

    @Column(name = "DATA")
    private Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

    ...    
}
```

Usage:

```
Test t = new Test();
t.getData().put("name", "James");
t.getData().put("number", 1);
t.getData().put("now", new Date());
```

Expected json when persisted:

```
{
    "name" : "James"
    "number" : 1,
    "now" : 1438933526108
}
```

Comment: Why not just use Jackson to serialize/deserialize it to/from JSON?

Comment: Note that for Maps and other complex types you do need to use Jackson (or any other JSON serializer) to convert to and from String data in the `nullSafeGet` and `nullSafeSet` methods of your own `UserType`.