# org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111 for jsonobject with custom JsonPostgreSQLDialect

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jsonb, native-sql

1) I added custom dialect by extending PostgreSQL9Dialect which does  this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "jsonb");

2) public class JSONObjectUserType implements UserType {
}

3)  property name="xxxx" type="org.JSONObjectUserType" length="1000"

4)  I run hibernate native SQL query.

SQLQuery query1 = (SQLQuery) session.createSQLQuery(str.toString());

It is giving No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111.
str = "Select state from X"

Postgresql - column state is of type jsonb.

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974474/mapping-postgresql-json-column-to-hibernate-value-type)

Comment: Thanks Vlad. I want to retain POJO class variable type as JSOnObject and not as 'text'. How to do with that approach?