# Handling Postgres json datatype in slick, scala

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, sqldatatypes

I have a Postgres 'json' column in my schema.
This is my column mapping in my code:

```
def my_col = column[Option[String]]("my_col")
```

Which doesn't work, the stack trace I get when inserting says:

> column "my_col" is of type json but expression is of type character
>   varying

I tried this too:

```
def my_col = column[Option[String]]("my_col", O.SqlType("json"))
```

Which also yields the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping postgreSQL JSON column to Hibernate value type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974474/mapping-postgresql-json-column-to-hibernate-value-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there are no standard `json` data type in java/scala.
So you need to write 'wrapper'.
By the link below author did it handling json on db level:

http://www.pateldenish.com/2013/05/inserting-json-data-into-postgres-using-jdbc-driver.html

Answer (score 10):

So I found the the [`slick-pg`](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) solution to be the better way to get this to work.  If all you need is JSON support in your code, i.e. you have a DB column that you simply want to represent as a Play `JsValue` while using Postgres' JSON column type, you just need to write a profile that mixes in the appropriate functionality from the `slick-pg` package.

### Step 1: Add the necessary dependences

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg" % "0.18.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg_play-json" % "0.18.0"
```

### Step 2: Write a profile class

```
import com.github.tminglei.slickpg._
import slick.basic.Capability
import slick.jdbc.JdbcCapabilities

trait PostgresProfile extends ExPostgresProfile with PgPlayJsonSupport {
  def pgjson = "jsonb"

  override protected def computeCapabilities: Set[Capability] =
    super.computeCapabilities + JdbcCapabilities.insertOrUpdate

  override val api = PostgresJsonSupportAPI

  object PostgresJsonSupportAPI extends API with JsonImplicits
}

object PostgresProfile extends PostgresProfile
```

### Step 3: Use your new profile class

So you'll need to extend `HasDatabaseConfigProvider` but parameterize it with the trait that you defined in the step #2 above, e.g.

```
class MyEntityRepository @Inject() (
  protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider
  ... // plus whatever other components you need, probably an ExecutionContext
) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[PostgresProfile] {

  import PostgresProfile.api._
...
}
```

### Define your column

This is the easy part.  In the above class, `MyEntityRepository` write a private or package private Slick class that extends `Table` and simply define your column like this:

```
def someColumnName = column[JsValue]("some_column_name")
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways:

1. Use mapping like in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40820108/8442366).
2. Use [`slick-pg`](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) package.