# Spring JPA row_to_json PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Instead of creating an entity with column annotation, is it possible to get query result with column name? Like:

```
@Query(value = "select emp.emp_id, emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_division_id, emp_role_id," +
        "(select count(*) from cheers.ch_kudos where kudos_receiver_id = emp.emp_id) as received_kudos_num, " +
        "(select count(*) from cheers.ch_kudos where kudos_sender_id = emp.emp_id) as sent_kudos_num " +
        "from cheers.ch_employee as emp where emp.emp_active_flag =  'true'", 
        nativeQuery=true)   
List<Object> getAllEmployeesReport();
```

The return result only has values, but doesn't have column name.

Otherwise, it there a way to get PostgreSQL row_to_json result by Spring JPA?

```
@Query(value = "select row_to_json(t) from (select emp.emp_id, emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_division_id, emp_role_id," +
        "(select count(*) from cheers.ch_kudos where kudos_receiver_id = emp.emp_id) as received_kudos_num, " +
        "(select count(*) from cheers.ch_kudos where kudos_sender_id = emp.emp_id) as sent_kudos_num " +
        "from cheers.ch_employee as emp where emp.emp_active_flag =  'true') t", 
        nativeQuery=true)   
List<Object> getAllEmployeesReport();
```

It will throw JDBC 111 exception.

Comment: JDBC 111 exception? Please be more specific. A stack trace would help.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider the answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974474/mapping-postgresql-json-column-to-hibernate-value-type)