# hibernate json mapping with psql database

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

With JPA I try to map a object of a @Entity class  a postgres DB json column.

```
@Enity
public class MyEntity{

@NotNull
@ToString.Exclude
@Convert(converter = JsonSerializationConverter.class)
private Object value;
}
```

```
public class JsonSerializationConverter implements AttributeConverter<Object, String> {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final Object attribute) {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(attribute);
    }
```

When running locally it works works like a charm, but for unknown reason it fails running in azure cloud on k8n pod:

```
SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [value] in table [preference] found [json (Types#OTHER)], but expecting [varchar(255)
```

Mainly other [stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974474/mapping-postgresql-json-column-to-a-hibernate-entity-property) refer this: [postgre bug](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/265) and suggest to set
data-source-properties: stringtype=unspecified

This unfortunately does not fix the problem in azure kn8 ubuntu pod.
I tried all like:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:postgresql://xyz:5432/dbname?stringtype=unspecified
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.stringtype: unspecified
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason, why locally it worked was that
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: none (and validate in the K8n)

But for all ENVs this resolved the issue:

```
@Enity
public class MyEntity{

@NotNull
@ToString.Exclude
//this resolved the issue
@Column(name = "value", columnDefinition = "json")
@Convert(converter = JsonSerializationConverter.class)
private Object value;
}
```

just not for the zonky embedded postgre